# php file upload check if file is an image

Tags: php

i have a php script for image uploads but i need some code to check if the file is an image. And yes i know. This question have been asked multiple times already. However, my file input is sending the data as an array so i could not use the code that others sent on the other threads related to check if file is an image.

Here is my html form

```
<form action="functions/imgupload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="imgtitle">Image Title:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="imgtitle" id="imgtitle">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="imgdesc">Image Description:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="imgdesc" id="imgdesc">
  </div>
  <input type="file" name="img[]" id="fileToUpload" multiple>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

And here is my php code

```
<?php
include("../../config/config.php");
$img = $_FILES['img'];

if(!empty($img)) {
  $img_desc = reArrayFiles($img);

  foreach($img_desc as $val) {
    $newname = date('YmdHis',time()).mt_rand().'.jpg';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO gallery (imgsrc, title, description) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $newname, $_POST['imgtitle'], $_POST['imgdesc']);
    if($stmt->execute()) {
      move_uploaded_file($val['tmp_name'],'../../images/'.$newname);
      header("location: ../");
    }
  }
}

function reArrayFiles($file) {
  $file_ary = array();
  $file_count = count($file['name']);
  $file_key = array_keys($file);

  for($i=0;$i<$file_count;$i++) {
    foreach($file_key as $val) {
      $file_ary[$i][$val] = $file[$val][$i];
    }
  }

  return $file_ary;
}
```

Comment: Can you give us an output of your data? What does the `$img` variable print?

Comment: maybe this helps https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: just add accept="image/*" to your file upload tag

Comment: _“my file input is sending the data as an array so i could not […]”_ - that sounds like a rather cheap excuse for not trying anything to me, tbh. Whatever code you have found, is probably either checking this via the file name extension, or needs the actual path to the file to pass it on to getimagesize or sth like that. So all it should need, is a modification of the parameters that are passed to it, when you use it in your loop.

Comment: @pr1nc3 I'm trying to print out the data from the img variable but i just get errors about array to string conversion

Comment: use `print_r($img);`

Comment: Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => 800x600_Wallpaper_Blue_Sky.png ) [type] => Array ( [0] => image/png ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => C:\xampp\tmp\php7C9E.tmp ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 1114351 ) )

Comment: One nice example is here https://www.codexworld.com/upload-multiple-images-store-in-database-php-mysql/

Comment: @Saji i had a look at that example but i don't like how he wrote the code for sending the data to the database. Isn't that php script vulnerable to SQL Injection Attacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be it will help you,

```
if(!empty($_FILES['img'])) {
    $img = $_FILES['img'];

    foreach($img['name'] as $key => $name) {
        $type = $img['type'][ $key ];
        $type = strtolower($type);
        if($type == 'image/jpg' || $type == 'image/jpeg' || $type == 'image/png' || $type == 'image/gif'){
            $newname = date('YmdHis',time()).mt_rand().'.jpg';
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO gallery (imgsrc, title, description) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("sss", $newname, $_POST['imgtitle'], $_POST['imgdesc']);
            if($stmt->execute()) {
                move_uploaded_file($img['tmp_name'][ $key ],'../../images/'.$newname);
            }
        }
    }

    header("location: ../");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But i have no idea what i should add in the foreach loop. The image checks that i have found looks like this.

Comment: `if ($_FILES['file']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
  die("Upload failed with error code " . $_FILES['file']['error']);
}

$info = getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
if ($info === FALSE) {
  die("Unable to determine image type of uploaded file");
}

if (($info[2] !== IMAGETYPE_GIF) && ($info[2] !== IMAGETYPE_JPEG) && 
 ($info[2] !== IMAGETYPE_PNG)) {
  die("Not a gif/jpeg/png");
}`

Comment: Sorry for posting the code as a bunch of text. It may be very hard to read. But i dont know how to wrap it in a code box when i send a comment...

Comment: That's why you usually don't post code in the comments, hard to read. You can edit your question and paste relevant code there.

Comment: @TimLevinsson edit it and put the code between these `` `like this`

Comment: @xmastertje Thanks but i'm not sure if it made it more readable haha

Comment: @TimLevinsson no problem haha. i think it is